# How to display one message below other in chat app?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a chat app with HTML and JavaScript. But I can't make messages appear below each other. Here is my HTML code:

```
<div>
  <!-- Message input -->
  <textarea id="messageInput" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
  <span onclick="sendIt()" id="sendBtn" class="fa fa-send-o"></span>
</div>
  <!-- Messages will be displayed here -->
<div id="container">
  <p id="nextMessage"></p>  
</div>
```

And here is js:

```
var message = document.getElementById('messageInput');

function sendIt() {
  if (message.value == 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextMessage").innerHTML += message.value + "<br>"
    document.getElementById("nextMessage").style.display = "block"

    message.value = "";

    document.getElementById("messageInput").style.height = "40px"
  }
}
```

The problem is they don't leave space between each other when displayed.
I tried also with `textContent` instead of innerHTML but then I can't make markup. Please someone help me with that and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more description? How is it being displayed, can you attach a screenshot of the current behavior, and explain further what the desired behavior is?

Comment: Please format your code snippet.

Comment: Your code works well

Comment: It works well. Try to replace `span` with `button` and check. https://repl.it/@ManojKumar42/CarpalExtrasmallCustomers#index.html

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly. But if you want to change the appearance, you can put the message in tag and then give style:

this is an example of giving margin:

```
 document.getElementById("nextMessage").innerHTML += '<p style="margin-top: 20px">'+message.value + "</p>"
```

Comment: A more elegant approach may be to use a more appropriate HTML element: rather than a <p> use an ordered list (which is what a set of messages in a chat is).

Then use appendChild() to add new list items to the list:
https://codepen.io/foxbeefly/pen/VwjJrZL

Comment: yes, this is right. <p> tag is just an example to show that this can be done.

Comment: just put  direction: rtl  for  <ol> tag

Comment: Thank you very much php developer.Now it is working fine :)